# Reading a CSV value number fields

Tags: powershell

The following code works as long as the "code" field has characters in it. Can anyone shed light on what is wrong and how I can get it to display the "code" values that are only numbers?

```
    $lookup = "c:\products.csv"
    $value = "036"
    $csv = Import-Csv $lookup -Header("code","description")
    $csv | Where-Object {$_.code -eq $value}
```

Comment: Are you working on a locale that doesn't use comma as separator character? Use the `-Delimiter` to specify another a character like `;` in such a case.

Comment: This is super unclear.  Please provide a representative list of sample values, how they are currently treated, and how you want them to be treated.

Comment: Ok here is a snippet of the CSV file

Comment: 00556,Crumbs Chicken & Ham Pie
00559,K.Rst Salmon Terrine + Lem/Hors Lay
00560,Hot Smoked Salmon Terrine
MB006,Budgens - Muddy B' Classic Burger
0057,Meggle Butter Roll 10 x 500g
006,Ovidias Chocolate Cupido
00607,Sp. Aubergine + S'dried Tom Terrine

Comment: ok this is a mess. lets forget this and I'll take it to technet as this is now going to be too fiddly to add the comments I want. thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

This will import the c:\products.csv file and assign it two columns

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\products.csv -Header Code,Description
```

To display Code number values only (Integers) using the -as operator:

```
$csv | Where-Object { $_.Code -as [int] }
```

Comment: The -as [int] is useful but not what I'm after thanks. The "code" column can contain numbers & characters & mixed. I want to be able to search for any of them. At the moment it will only display fields that only have characters or mixed.

Comment: Your question was: ... display the "code" values that are only numbers. Anyway, try to list example values and the code you use to list them, it will help identify your problem. Your where-object example filters code values that only -eq a string '036'.